# How to solve a single dot product inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, linear-programming

We have an inequality of real numbers:
$$ a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + \dots + a_nx_n \ge 0. $$

Is there a way to express the most precise bounds $\{l_i$, $u_i\}$, in function of the $\{x_j\}$, such that $\forall i, a_i \in [l_i,u_i]$ ?

Comment: What do you mean "most precise"?  You want $a_i \in [l_i,u_i]$ to hold for all possible configurations where the inequality holds for a fixed set of $\{x_j\}$?  This is unlikely to yield any bounds better than $(-\infty, +\infty)$, except for maybe one bound of the form $[0,+\infty)$ and that is only in a degenerate case where almost all $x_j=0$.

Comment: I don't get it, if almost all $x_j$s are zero, then a few are not and I would still be interested in a solution to this. I don't mind if some or most $l_i$,$u_i$ are $-\infty$, $+\infty$. For instance, for the case $n=1$, we would have $a_1 \in [0,+\infty)$ or $(-\infty,0]$

Comment: If you have any $x_j=0$ then this reduces to the lower-dimensional case where we ignore coordinate $j$.  The case $n=1$ is in this sense the only case where we can say anything about $l_i$ or $u_i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Erick Wongs answer in the comments, imagine that $n = 2$ or $3$ so that you can draw a picture. Let's say $n = 3$ for now. $x := (x_1, x_2, x_3)$ is a point in 3-dimensional space. The set of all vectors $(b_1, b_2, b_3)$ such that $b_1x_1 + b_2x_2 + b_3 x_3 = 0$ is an infinite plane through the origin: it is the plane of vectors that are orthogonal to the line passing through $0$ and $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$. Let's call this plane $P$. Now the set of points $(a_1, a_2, a_3)$ you describe make up HALF OF ALL SPACE, namely all points that are on the same side of $P$ as point $x$ is. Now look only at the first coordinates that are possible for points in this half space. For almost all choices of $x$ (that is: of $P$) they can be any number. Only in the special case that $x$ is of the form $(x_1, 0, 0)$ we have that the half space consists of all points $(a_1, a_2, a_3)$ where $a_1 \geq 0$ with no further conditions on $a_2$ and $a_3$ (or, if $x_1 < 0$, where $a_1 \leq 0$ with no conditions on $a_2, a_3$).

So the answer is one of two cases:

A. $(-\infty, \infty)$ for all coordinates

B. $(-\infty, \infty)$ for all but one coordinates and for one special coordinate either $(-\infty, 0]$ or $[0, \infty)$.